# Сделать два html элемента main и aside одинаковой высоты

Tags: html, html5, css

Как бы ты реализовал задачу - сделать два html элемента main и aside одинаковой высоты, причем независимо от количества контента в каждой из них?

То есть у одной высота от наполнения контента 100px, у другой 900px. Обе должны стать 900px.

Answer (score 5):

Пишем обоим `padding-bottom: 10000px; margin-bottom: -10000px;`, оборачиваем при необходимости в `overflow: hidden`.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы, при помощи js, присвоил высоте aside значение высоты main.

```
var innerHeight = $('.main').height();
$('aside').height(innerHeight);
```

Comment: @Дмитрий Клименко А если main меньше, чем aside?

Comment: @eprivalov1, вероятно, имеет смысл указать некоторую минимальную для main.

@deivan, c тех пор, как ваши костыли полетят вместе с футером, который @eprivalov1 наверняка захочет прижать к низу страницы в подобном проекте, где у контентной части будет разная высота и наполнение. Не хамите. Если я не прав, на это можно указать в другой манере.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/q2zdqr9e/ - а такой вариант подходит?